# What does "Shahdaroba" mean?

Tags: rock, song-title, etymology

Asking about the title of Roy Orbison's 1963 song "Shahdaroba." It seems to have some tenuous Middle Eastern derivation (the song begins "Where the Nile flows...").
You might be familiar with this song from the season three finale of "Mad Men."

Answer (score -2):

The closest literal Arabic translation might use two words "jahad' and 'aroba', however the word shahdaroba means the future is better than the past.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).